# XCUITestcode in Stable Branch?

Tags: xcode, automated-tests, xcuitest

I have question around best practices. Where should XCUItest live ?

- "Stable" branch is what goes to app stores. Is it wrong for test to live in stable branch ?
- Will the presence of XCUITest code or other testing code in my project lead to a rejection from the App Store?

Researched developer.apple.com/forums.
No response to question https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737518
Googled ,ChatGpt with no clear answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it belongs with your production code. As it isn't built into the production application it has no effect on what users receive so no, no effect on App Store reviews either.